# sintaxis para array de hashes y hash de hashes en ruby?

Tags: ruby

Ya revise la documentación oficial pero no halle, quizás busque mal.
Algún ebook o blog con sintaxis Ruby para iterar y ordenar:

- array de hashes
- hash de hashes

---

**Ejemplo Array of Hash, ordenar en ascendente por precio.**

Entrada

```
[
  {"producto":"Vino tinto","precio":950.50},
  {"producto":"Carne res 1 Kg","precio":450.99},
  {"producto":"Cebolla blanca","precio":59.50}
]
```

Salida

```
  {"producto":"Cebolla blanca","precio":59.50}
  {"producto":"Carne res 1 Kg","precio":450.99}
  {"producto":"Vino tinto","precio":950.50}
```

---

**Ejemplo Hash of Hashes, ordenar en ascendente por precio**

Entrada

```
{
  {"producto":"Vino tinto","precio":950.50},
  {"producto":"Carne res 1 Kg","precio":450.99},
  {"producto":"Cebolla blanca","precio":59.50}
}
```

Salida

```
  {"producto":"Cebolla blanca","precio":59.50}
  {"producto":"Carne res 1 Kg","precio":450.99}
  {"producto":"Vino tinto","precio":950.50}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ordernar un array de hashes, puedes ocupar el método [`.sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) de la siguiente forma:

```
irb(main):001:0> array = [
  {"producto":"Vino tinto","precio":950.50},
  {"producto":"Carne res 1 Kg","precio":450.99},
  {"producto":"Cebolla blanca","precio":59.50}
]
=> [{:producto=>"Vino tinto", :precio=>950.5}, {:producto=>"Carne res 1 Kg", :precio=>450.99}, {:producto=>"Cebolla blanca", :precio=>59.5}]
irb(main):002:0> array.sort_by {|e| e[:precio]}
=> [{:producto=>"Cebolla blanca", :precio=>59.5}, {:producto=>"Carne res 1 Kg", :precio=>450.99}, {:producto=>"Vino tinto", :precio=>950.5}]
```

Respecto a un hash de hashes... no a se que te refieras, pero eso no existe en ruby. Cuando tu escribes esto:

```
{
  {"producto":"Vino tinto","precio":950.50},
  {"producto":"Carne res 1 Kg","precio":450.99},
  {"producto":"Cebolla blanca","precio":59.50}
}
```

Lo que defines como el "hash" principal que contiene los otros hashes, no tiene la estructura de clave/valor que componen a los elementos de un hash. De hecho, creo que tienes un concepto erróneo sobre [los hashes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla_hash), porque independiente del lenguaje, el solo concepto de "ordenar" un hash no existe (que yo tenga entendido).
Lo que puedes hacer es, desde un hash, generar un array con elementos ordenados, pero tampoco aplicaría para tu "hash de hashes", porque en un hash la clave de cada elemento tiene que ser un valor único en el hash, que en tu caso podría ser el valor del producto, pero no se si efectivamente sea eso lo que requieres.

Comment: considerare cada una de tus palabras mi estimado @AlterLagos , probare el codigo.

Comment: Me fue util. Gracias @AlterLagos por tu tiempo y aportación